# How to automatic close the Command window when a wolframescript is end of operation？

Tags: scripting

I have generated a `.wls` file in Mathematica 11.  A command window will appear when the `.wls` runs, but the command window will not disappear automatically when the run ends.

Comment: I have not used .wls. But what happens if you put `Quit[]` as last command in the script?

Comment: @ Nasser Nothing happens.   @m_goldberg my computer is win10.

Comment: When I double-click on a .wls file in the Finder on my system, macOS 10.13.4, a Terminal window appears on my screen while the script is running. The Terminal app exits as soon as the script completes and the window closes. So the behavior you describe doesn't happen on my system.